# How can get the first object of a json array from html file in angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a json file (product.json) as below which is located in src/assets/ :

```
 [
{
  "images": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png",
  "textBox": "empty",
  "comments": "empty"
},
   {
  "images": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png",
  "textBox": "empty",
  "comments": "empty"
},
  {
  "images": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/73/rejon_Hammer.png",
  "textBox": "empty",
  "comments": "empty"
},
  {
  "images": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/27070/egore911_saw.png",
  "textBox": "empty",
  "comments": "empty"
}
,
  {
  "images": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/120337/xbox-controller_01.png",
  "textBox": "empty",
  "comments": "empty"
  },
    {
  "images": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/120337/xbox-controller_01.png",
  "textBox": "empty",
  "comments": "empty"
}

  ]
```

My interface is as below:

export interface IWidgets {

```
images: string;
textBox: string;
comments: string;
  }
```

grid.service.ts is as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { IWidgets } from './widget';
import {IBox} from './grid'



@Injectable()
export class WidgetService {

 private _widgetUrl = './assets/widgetConfig.json';

 constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getWidgets(): Observable<IWidgets[]> {

    return this._http.get(this._widgetUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IWidgets[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
 }
```

grid.component.ts is defined as below

```
 import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
 import {NgGrid, NgGridItem, NgGridConfig, NgGridItemConfig, NgGridItemEvent} from 'angular2-grid';
 import {IBox} from './grid'
 import {WidgetService} from './grid.service'
 import {IWidgets} from './widget'



@Component({
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [WidgetService]

 })

 export class GridComponent {

private boxes: Array<IBox> = [];
private rgb: string = '#efefef';
private curNum;
widgets: IWidgets[];
errorMessage: string;
private gridConfig: NgGridConfig = <NgGridConfig>{
    // some properites here
};
 private itemPositions: Array<any> = [];

 constructor(private _widgetService : WidgetService) {

    const dashconf = this._generateDefaultDashConfig(); 

    for (var i = 0; i < dashconf.length; i++) { //6
        const conf = dashconf[i]; 
        conf.payload = 1 + i;
        this.boxes[i] = { id: i + 1, config: conf,name: "widget " + conf.payload + " : "};
    }
    this.curNum = dashconf.length + 1; //6


}

ngOnInit(): void {

this._widgetService.getWidgets()
    .subscribe(widgets=> this.widgets=widgets,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any> error);

}
```

Now widgets holds all the objects with their properties of the Json file above

I want now to access the first object of this Json file in a html file but everytime I do something I got an undefined value.

I know to do it in this way :

```
    <div *ngFor="let widget of widgets">
      <ul>
     <li>{{widget.images}}</li>
     <li>{{widget.textBox}}</li>
     <li>{{widget.comments}}</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

But in my occasion I want to access inside another for the first object of this Json file. The other for loop is like below

```
   <div *ngFor="let box of boxes; let i = index;">

   // here I want to access the first object of the JSON file 

   </div>
```

I need some help since I have some problems with the syntax of Angular2 in html files.

Comment: Put in your html:  {{ "widgets: " + widgets.length}}. What is result?

Comment: @HassanFalahi It is 6 as it is expected

Comment: Please share your code in plunker or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you need to access **only** the first element of your JSON you can access it like this :

```
<ul>
     <li>{{widgets[0].images}}</li>
     <li>{{widgets[0].textBox}}</li>
     <li>{{widgets[0].comments}}</li>
</ul>
```

If you're trying to have one loop to loop on `boxes` and another one looping on `widget`you can do it like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let box of boxes" >
     <div *ngFor="let widget of widgets">
            <ul>
              <li>{{widget.images}}</li>
              <li>{{widget.textBox}}</li>
              <li>{{widget.comments}}</li>
           </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I do it like the first way I got the following error:  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Then that means that your `widgets` object is `undefined`. You should check if your JSON is properly loaded.

Comment: It is properly loaded because if I do it with the second way it works but in this case all my json file is loaded to each box but I want first object of the json file to be loaded to the first box, the second object of json file to be loaded to the second box and so on, that is why I do not want to use the second way since the result is not the desired one

Comment: What does the console display when you put a `console.log(widgets)` (After loading the json) ?

Comment: Sorry it displays an empty array